# Displaying Volume profile on a javascript chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, stocks

Is there any javascript charting library that supports volume profile. I'd like to display a stock chart and a corresponding volume profile chart, either integrated with the chart or on a panel to the side of the chart.

e.g https://www.tradingview.com/stock-charts-support/index.php/Volume_Profile

Thanks

[image]

Comment: does it have to be on the side like that? have you tried HighStocks?

Comment: Shame this question is closed, as SciChart.js supports Volume Profile. Here's a Codepen showing how to do it per candle https://codepen.io/scichart/pen/abRpzMv and another codepen showing how to do it once at the right of the chart https://codepen.io/scichart/pen/YzJZgvd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to recommend High Stocks here: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo

No need to combine charts, as this is exactly what its for!

JSFiddle of `AAPL` with volume: http://jsfiddle.net/32srwqs1/

Comment: And although I don't understand why you'd want it on the side, if it really needs to be like that, you do that with two charts in highcarts as well.  Example with a run chart/histogram:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/r2Lvo2dw/

Answer (score 2):

[ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com/) is a JavaScript charting library that supports stock and volume charts. To get started, I recommend reading our [Stock Charts Tutorial](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/stock-charts/), just to get an overview of what you can do with the chart type. Here's a basic stock and volume chart created with blended scales. The "stock" and "volume" portions share the same x-axis time-series scale.

[image]

http://demos.zingchart.com/view/PVTPGND4

There are many ways to customize this chart type. Here is another example that incorporates a zooming scrollbar and dynamic labels/crosshairs. Click the links to interact with the chart.

[image]

http://demos.zingchart.com/view/ULASOO3O

I'm on the ZingChart team. Let me know if you have more questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/technicalindicators as a node library or directly from the browser.